# titlepage with hyperref in overleaf not working

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, hyperlink

My goal is to create a title page with links like the first page of the pdfrender package available here: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdfrender.pdf

On the side, there's a bookmark and it has color hyperref. (I want have the same front page as the pdfrender title page. On the left side, you see the bookmarks. On the front page, you see the blue hyperref. That's what I want. The codes from overleaf produce the pdf but when I upload it to google drive, it doesn't do it.)

I like to know how so I find a similar template at overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/3739199258sncjysqnwkjh

I print out the pdf and upload it to google drive.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVt-Pa8qXUuN2Ht_RMgxJX2WqYDXMxID/view

The hyperlink is not working, no bookmark.

Did I miss anything in the instruction? Please advise. I am new to Latex.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
    bookmarks=true,
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

This will be an empty chapter and I will put some text here

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:1} shows a sum that is divergent. This formula will be latter used in the page \pageref{second}.

For further references see \href{http://www.sharelatex.com}{Something Linky} or go to the next url: \url{http://www.sharelatex.com} or open the next file \href{run:./file.txt}{File.txt}

It's also possible to link directly any word or \hyperlink{thesentence}{any sentence} in you document.

If you read this text, you will get noinformation.  Really?  Is there no information?

For instance \hypertarget{thesentence}{this sentence}.


\Blindtext

\clearpage

\section{Second section} \label{second}

\blindtext



\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

Comment: Even logged in to overleaf the linked project says "permission error"

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this. My mistake. But I did provide the MWE from overleaf. Those are the codes that are in the template.

Comment: @user92127 The Overleaf URL here does not grant access to your project to other users - if you could click "Share", then "Turn on link-sharing", there will be a read-only link that you can put here to let others access your project. PS I'm on support staff at Overleaf, we'll be happy to help if you email us at support@overleaf.com .

Comment: @walszje - I updated the link to reflect the sharing.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your suggestion. After trying so many pdf and using them with different pdf viewers, the problem lies with google pdf viewer. It doesn't work and it will not allow you to see bookmark or using hyperlinks/hyperrefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `article` class to get such a title page. You will need to change from chapters to sections and use `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
    bookmarks=true,
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

\urlstyle{same}

\title{text}
\author{names}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First Chapter}

This will be an empty chapter and I will put some text here

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:1} shows a sum that is divergent. This formula will be latter used in the page \pageref{second}.

For further references see \href{http://www.sharelatex.com}{Something Linky} or go to the next url: \url{http://www.sharelatex.com} or open the next file \href{run:./file.txt}{File.txt}

It's also possible to link directly any word or \hyperlink{thesentence}{any sentence} in you document.

If you read this text, you will get noinformation.  Really?  Is there no information?

For instance \hypertarget{thesentence}{this sentence}.


\Blindtext

\clearpage

\section{Second section} \label{second}

\blindtext



\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understand you right, you have the following issues:

1. There is no title printed in your code. You missed to add `\maketitle` and related commands `\title{Title}` and `\author{John Doe}`. Please see the following mwe ...
2. The art of title depends on the used documentclass. `book` creates one complete page to be titlepage, class `article` creates an title at the begin of the article, text follows imieadtly -- and it seems that is what you want. So you need to change documentclass `book` to `article` (You then have also to change `\chapter{}` to `\section{}` ...
3. The issue woth the bookmarks can depend on your used pdf viewer. Some pdf viewer show bookmarks without special option, some not. To be more sure add the oprtion `bookmarksopen,` to `hyperref` to get an open bookmark shown by opening the pdf in the viewer ...
4. To show you that the hyperref is working I changend the color `blue` to `green`. If you click the green lines in the TOC in the resulting pdf of my mwe you will get the clicked page be showed ...

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article} % book

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=green, % <================================ your color was blue
  filecolor=magenta,      
  urlcolor=cyan,
  pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
% bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen, % <====================================================
  pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\urlstyle{same}
\title{test}
\author{John Doe}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

%\chapter{First Chapter}  % <============================ start with class book
\section{First Section}   % <============================ start with class article

This will be an empty chapter and I will put some text here

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:1} shows a sum that is divergent. This formula will be latter used in the page \pageref{second}.

For further references see \href{http://www.sharelatex.com}{Something Linky} or go to the next url: \url{http://www.sharelatex.com} or open the next file \href{run:./file.txt}{File.txt}

It's also possible to link directly any word or \hyperlink{thesentence}{any sentence} in you document.

If you read this text, you will get noinformation.  Really?  Is there no information?

For instance \hypertarget{thesentence}{this sentence}.


\Blindtext

\clearpage

\section{Second section} \label{second}

\blindtext



\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

BTW: I compiled with my current MiKTeX 2.9 without errors or warnings!

Comment: Thank you for your time. As I mentioned, I didn't do anything on the template. I just copy and test it. I will apply your advice.